# Pass by value in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking at understanding objective-c and I came into a problem in tapping the screen and incrementing the count variable which I store in my appdelegate.

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSInteger)num {
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", num];
    countLabel.text = s;
    [s release];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    TestAppDelegate *aDel = (TestAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    aDel.count++;
    NSInteger num = aDel.count;
    [self updateLabel:num];
}
```

I get the EXC_BAD_ACS which to me says I'm trying to access something I'm not.  It looks like I cannot send updateLabel the num variable because the scope of the primitive type goes away at the end of the method and then when updateLabel tries to access it, I get the error?  I wanted to know if I understood this concept correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: You've made a good attempt at showing your thinking. But the code in `updateLabel` runs *before* `touchedBegan` finishes so anything passed to it would not go out of scope. taskinoor has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that `NSInteger` is not an object, see its definition by cmd-clicking the keyword:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE …
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Which means that your method to update the label should look a bit like this:

```
- (void) updateLabel: (NSInteger) num {
    countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", num];
}
```

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem. However I am still confused though since I thought initWithFormat and stringWithFormat were the same except with initWithFormat you were responsible to clean up the memory, and stringWithFormat autoreleased the string.  Looking at the Apple header files, it says that initWithFormat returns NSString, and stringWithFormat returns a string.  Still, I didn't know if there was a real difference between the two, but obviously one works and one does not?  Any other htoughts?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The difference is not in initWithFormat Vs stringWithFormat. The difference is in format specifier. You can not use %@ for integer. You need to use %d or %i.

Answer (score 2):

```
// format specifier for integer is %d, not %@
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", num];
```

`num` is not out of scope here. You are passing it by value to `updateLabel`. Please also check that `countLabel` is not already released when you are calling `updateLabel`.

And you can pass `aDel.count` directly to the `updateLabel`. There is no need of temporary `num` variable.

```
[self updateLabel:aDel.count];
```

Comment: I don't release countLabel until my dealloc method.  Is there another way I could be accessing bad memory here?